# Filtro em update de uma tabela com base informações de uma outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, preciso fazer um `UPDATE` em uma tabela (no exemplo a tabela 'reservas'), com base em informações de uma outra tabela (no exemplo a tabela 'administracao'). Bom até ai consegui fazer com a ajuda de uma pessoa aqui do fórum...

Exemplo do que já tenho: (realiza o update na tabela 'reservas' se não existir a duplicação dos mesmos registro na tabela 'administracao').

`UPDATES reservas t1 SET t1.status_reserva = 'Entregue' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM administracao t2 WHERE t2.cod = t1.cod1 )`

Agora preciso fazer isso, só que colocando um filtro para que o `UPDATE` execute apenas se o campo 'status_reserva' for diferente da palavra 'Cancelado'.

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma, porem não funcionou:

`UPDATES reservas t1 SET t1.status_reserva = 'Entregue' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM administracao t2 WHERE t2.cod = t1.cod1 ) AND status_reserva != 'Cancelado'`

Por favor, alguém que tenha uma solução para esse problema, ou se não é possível fazer isso?!

Comment: O possível problema seria que você não está indicando de qual tabela pegar essa coluna `status_reserva`? Que no caso seria da seguinte forma `t1.status_reserva`

Comment: :( Não deu certo. Dessa forma não executa o Update, ele não reconhece se o campo `status_reserva` está ou não preenchido com a palavra `Cancelado`, haveria outra solução?

Comment: Postei duas soluções as quais necessito que teste em seu código, pois não estou com meios de testar no momento! Haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia simplesmente estar fazendo um `LEFT JOIN` e verificando se ele é `NULL` no final... Ficaria algo +/- dessa maneira:

```
UPDATE reservas t1
LEFT JOIN administracao t2
ON t2.cod = t1.cod1
SET t1.status_reserva = 'Entregue'
WHERE t2.cod IS NULL && t1.status_reserva != 'Cancelado';
```

Ou até mesmo passar a condição do `status_reserva` para antes do **EXISTS**:

```
UPDATES reservas t1 SET t1.status_reserva = 'Entregue' WHERE t1.status_reserva != 'Cancelado' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM administracao t2 WHERE t2.cod = t1.cod1 )
```

Veja se algum deles se adequa ao que você deseja fazer em seu código... :)

Comment: Consegui com a segunda solução apresentada, muito obrigado!!!